# wix # script for creating a installer

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, wixsharp

I have a wpf application which helps  user to selects the directory path and when he click create installer button then I want to create installer for user selected directory(inside directory there may me more than one file).

I came to know that I can use a wix# script and then I call this script when button is clicked. But I don't know how to write a wix# script which take input for file (the file for that installer is going to create).

I am familier with basic wix and new to wix #. Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the Wixsharp solution.

You can get it from the nuget reference option (Visual studio), then you just need to write the code so it works like you want it.

I'll make a C# example:

```
static string sRootDir = @"<Path of Source directory>";
static void BuildMSI()
        {                                  
            WixEntity[] weDir = new WixEntity[0];
            weDir = BuildDirInfo(sRootDir, weDir);
            var project = new Project("My product", weDir)
            {
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                //UI = WUI.WixUI_InstallDir,
                Version = new Version(55, 0, 0, 0),
                UpgradeCode = guidUpgradeCode, // Forwarded if upgrading existing product
                MajorUpgradeStrategy = new MajorUpgradeStrategy
                {
                    UpgradeVersions = VersionRange.OlderThanThis,
                    PreventDowngradingVersions = VersionRange.NewerThanThis,
                    NewerProductInstalledErrorMessage = "Newer version already installed"
                }
            };

            project.BuildMsi(project);
        }



static WixEntity[] BuildDirInfo(string sRootDir, WixEntity[] weDir)
        {
            DirectoryInfo RootDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sRootDir);
            if (RootDirInfo.Exists)
            {
                DirectoryInfo[] DirInfo = RootDirInfo.GetDirectories();
                List<string> lMainDirs = new List<string>();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo DirInfoSub in DirInfo)
                    lMainDirs.Add(DirInfoSub.FullName);
                int cnt = lMainDirs.Count;
                weDir = new WixEntity[cnt + 1];
                if (cnt == 0)
                    weDir[0] = new DirFiles(RootDirInfo.FullName + @"\*.*");
                else
                {
                    weDir[cnt] = new DirFiles(RootDirInfo.FullName + @"\*.*");
                    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo RootSubDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(lMainDirs[i]);
                        if (!RootSubDirInfo.Exists)
                            continue;
                        WixEntity[] weSubDir = new WixEntity[0];
                        weSubDir = BuildDirInfo(RootSubDirInfo.FullName, weSubDir);
                        weDir[i] = new Dir(RootSubDirInfo.Name, weSubDir);
                    }
                }
            }
            return weDir;
        }
```